'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command
Why does this code work, only when I replace the mv with move?
forfiless /c "cmd /c mv @FILE @FNAME_changed.@EXT"

Generally the short form mv works just well, but when I use it with the forfiles command it says:

'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 



Unfortunately the command you submitted does not produce the message you have displayed. It would output: 'forfiless' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.. Also, to be clear, you are not running mv in forfiles, you are specifying to run it in cmd.

To clarify, mv is a command alias for the PowerShell Move-Item cmdlet. Therefore, if you wish to use it, you need to do so in powershell, not cmd. Example: forfiles /c "powershell -c mv @file @fname_changed.@ext. That should work if you invoke it within a PowerShell Prompt, or a Command Prompt, window. Alternatively you could have used a more appropriate command, ren. This works in both powershell.exe , (where it's an alias for Rename-Item), or cmd.exe. e.g. forfiles /c "powershell -c ren @file @fname_changed.@ext", (just replace powershell -c with cmd /c as needed).

move is a recognized command in Windows and this is why it works. mv is not a recognized command in forfiles. mv is a recognized and known Linux command for moving files and it's also known in Powershell, so you either ran it directly in Powershell (valid) or ssh-d to a Linux server and executed mv (valid) or something else, but when you try to do it in forfiles, then it's invalid.
